# Questions related to 'npm install' and 'node_modules'

Tags: node-modules, npm-install

When executing the 'npm install' command in a node project,
Is there a way to prevent certain directories (packages) in the node_modules directory from being updated?

In other words, is there a way to avoid touching the specific directory (package) itself in node_modules?

(I'm using a package that is not defined in the 'package.json file' content by manually putting it inside the 'node_modules directory'. I hope the package is not deleted when commanding 'npm install'.)

Comment: In short no, in long nope

Comment: If you are manually copying it in, npm doesn't know it exists.  So it won't update the folder, but it won't do anything to protect it either.  There are plenty of ways to do a local install.  And you could just have the module in the source directory and not deal with whatever extra work it takes to put something in node_modules.

Answer (score 2):

This situation is little complicated but you can try creating your private package.

the below test works, you can give it a try:

I have created a dummy package "foo" with:

```
"name": "@my-private-namespace/foo",
```

I created a folder:

```
$ npm init -y
...
$ npm install ../foo
...
$ ls node_modules/\@my-private-namespace/
foo
$ npm install n
...
$ ls node_modules/\@my-private-namespace/
foo
```

Comment: '@my-private-namespace' <-- this mean the dummy package path??

Comment: Yes, path to the dummy package